# DrawText in CGRect for PDF

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics

I'm trying to create a PDF and I have some text.  It is longer than one line, so I'm not sure how I need to write it into my context.  Do I calculate a CGRect the size of my text first?  From there, how would I do word wrap or things like that in creating a PDF?  So far all I've been able to do is to just draw a title at the correct location :-.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Core Text, as this is a fairly powerful text rendering framework that plays nicely with Quartz. What you're trying to do is easily accomplished using the CTFrame class.